# Add large brace next to table (Beamer): Description included

Tags: tables, brackets, braces

I created the following table:

```
\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{7.5cm}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\centering
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\midrule
A &$a \sim \qty{e6}{m}$\\
B &$b \sim \qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}$\\
C &$c \sim \qty{e8}{m.s^{-2}}$\\
\begin{rcases}
\textnormal{D}\\
\textnormal{E}\\
\end{rcases} &$d \sim \qty{e2}{K}$\\
F &$f = \qty{e-3}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\hspace{7.5cm}
\end{columns}
```

I would like to add a bracket to the right side of the table as shown in the screenshot and I would like to place a text next to the bracket containing several quantities.

[image]

I found other questions on that topic, but I could not use them for my specific example. Do you know how I could do it?

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[serif,10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs} % package for table
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for units and numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\frame{{title}{}

\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{7.5cm}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\centering
\caption{Test table}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\midrule
A &$a \sim \qty{e6}{m}$\\
B &$b \sim \qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}$\\
C &$c \sim \qty{e8}{m.s^{-2}}$\\
\begin{rcases}
\textnormal{D}\\
\textnormal{E}\\
\end{rcases} &$d \sim \qty{e2}{K}$\\
F &$f = \qty{e-3}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\hspace{7.5cm}
\end{columns}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I am sorry, I have not thought about that! Latex is still new to me. I added additional comments. 
Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the `serif` class option is deprecated. Use `\usefonttheme{serif}` instead (this will also avoid the warning in the log file about this)
- `rcases` needs to be in math mode. Please don't ignore error messages.
- floating specifier like `[ht]` don't make a lot of sense in a document class without floating mechanism
- you don't need `\centering`, tables are automatically centred in beamer
- you could use the `tabularray` package to create a table with a large brace on the right hand side:

---

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{booktabs} % package for table
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for units and numbers
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  \begin{table}
    \small
    \caption{Test table}
    \begin{+array}{
      delimiter = {right=\rbrace, left=.},
      column{2} = {mode={imath}}
    }
    \midrule
      A & a \sim \qty{e6}{m}\\
      B & b \sim \qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}\\
      C & c \sim \qty{e8}{m.s^{-2}}\\
      $\begin{rcases}
      \text{D}\\
      \text{E}\\
      \end{rcases}$ & d \sim \qty{e2}{K}\\
      F & f = \qty{e-3}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{+array} 
    Description
  \end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is prefect, thank you so much!

Comment: @Sylvia You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Use the current recommended syntax:

- `\usefonttheme{serif}` rather than the option `serif`
- `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` rather than `\frame{...}`

Next you can use `nicetabular`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{booktabs} % package for table
\usepackage{siunitx} % package for units and numbers
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Section1}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}

\begin{columns}[c]
\begin{column}{7.5cm}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
\centering
\caption{Test table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{} l l @{}}
\toprule
A &$a \sim \qty{e6}{m}$ \\
B &$b \sim \qty{e-4}{s^{-1}}$\\
C &$c \sim \qty{e8}{m.s^{-2}}$\\
D & \Block{2-1}{$d \sim \qty{e2}{K}$} \\
E & \\
F &$f = \qty{e-3}{m^2.s^{-2}.K}$\\
\bottomrule
\CodeAfter\SubMatrix.{4-1}{5-1}\}\SubMatrix.{1-2}{6-2}\}
\end{NiceTabular}
$\quad\begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{matrix}$

\end{table}
\end{column}
\hspace{7.5cm}
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a beautiful solution. However, the description switches from right to bottom when I edit the table entries. Did that occur to you?

Comment: @Sylvia I guess you ***don't*** want the description on the side or to increase the allotted width.